# Page keeps reload after clicking the Disable/Enable in php

Tags: javascript, php, database, reload

In our page, there is 1 input that has to be manually enter by user. Upon what he has entered, some records has been shown and there is Disable or Enable beside each results(Example, I input `12345` and results are `A`,`B`,`C`,`D`, 4 results and beside of those results, there will be disable button side.). Currently, what is happening is when I click Disable or Enable, the page reload automatically and I can't find a way to fix it. Is there anyway to stop reloading? I use `window.history.go(-1)`. it update the database but the page keeps reload every time I disable or enable.[image: As you can see in the picture for result.]
Below is `HTML` codes.

```
<body onload="OnLoad()">
```

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="translot" method="post">

<form id="form" method="post">
<div class="col" style="width: 580px; font-weight: bold; border: 1px solid SteelBlue; color: #6699CC; margin-left: 170px;">
    <p style="background-color: #6699CC; font-size: 16px; width: 580px; padding: 5px; color: #FFF; font-weight: bold; margin-left: -1px;margin-top: -1px;"></p>

<div class="form-group">



  <br>
  <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="productlotid">Lot ID:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <p class="form-control-static" style="margin-top: -6px;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productlotid" name="productlotid" onkeydown="return KeyDown()" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()" onkeypress="return searchKeyPress(event)" min="1" placeholder="Enter Lot ID" value="<?php echo $productlotid; ?>">
    </p>
    <?php
                include("correlationwafer_result.php");
    ?>
  </div>
  <div id="result" style="display: inline-table; margin-left: 150px; margin-top: 22px;"></div>
  <!--div id="result" ></div-->
  <div class="col-sm-10">
   </div>
  <br>


</div>
</div>
<br>
```

```
 <div style="margin-right: 65px;">
<p align="center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info " name="cmdSubmit" id="cmdSubmit" onclick="Submit()"><b>Go</b></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" name="cmdReset" onclick="Reset()"><b>Reset</b></button></p>
</div>


</form>

</form>
```

Below is php code from `correlationwafer_result.php`.

```
   <?php 

// ini_set("memory_limit","512M");
include("_dbconn.php");
include("//sgewsnant21.amk.st.com/ewsweb/wwwroot/library/common7/db_config.inc");
include("//sgewsnant21.amk.st.com/ewsweb/wwwroot/library/common7/standard_defines.inc");
session_start();


$productlotid = isset ($_GET['productlotid'])? $_GET['productlotid']:'';

//$sql1 = "Update * FROM productdb.tbl_correlationwafer WHERE lotid = '$productlotid' ORDER BY lotid and zone_enable='0'";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM productdb.tbl_correlationwafer WHERE lotid = '$productlotid' ORDER BY product asc, zone asc";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

echo "<table id='corwafer'>";
$arr = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {

$field1name = $row["lotid"];
$field2name = $row["product"];
$field3name = $row["ewsflow"];
$field4name = $row["zone"];
$field5name = $row["zone_enable"];
$key = $field1name + ":" + $field2name + ":" + $field3name;

if (!in_array($key, $arr)){
    array_push($arr, $key);
}
?>
<form action='test.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<?php    
   echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    if($field5name == 1){
        echo "<input type='hidden' id='chkzone' name='chkzone' value='$field4name'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' id='pid' name='pid' value='$field1name'>";
        echo" <label for='chkzone'> Product - $field2name </label>";
        echo" <label for='chkzone'> :: Zone - $field4name </label>";
        //echo" <label for='chkzone'> :: Zone - $field4name </label>";
        
        echo "<a class='btn btn-secondary text-light btn-sm' href='test.php?id=$field4name&pid=$field1name'>Disable</a>";
    } 
    else if($field5name == 0){
        echo "<input type='hidden' id='chkzone' name='chkzone' value='$field4name'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' id='pid' name='pid' value='$field1name'>";
        echo" <label for='chkzone'> Product - $field2name </label>";
        echo" <label for='chkzone'> :: Zone - $field4name </label>";
        //echo" <label for='chkzone'> :: Zone - $field4name </label>";
        
        echo "<a class='btn btn-secondary text-light btn-sm' href='test_1.php?id=$field4name&pid=$field1name'>Enable</a>";
    }
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    ?>
    </form>
<?php
}


echo "</table>";

flush();
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Below codes are from `test.php` page.

```
    <?php 

// ini_set("memory_limit","512M");
include("_dbconn.php");
include("//sgewsnant21.amk.st.com/ewsweb/wwwroot/library/common7/db_config.inc");
include("//sgewsnant21.amk.st.com/ewsweb/wwwroot/library/common7/standard_defines.inc");
session_start();

        $zone = $_GET['id'];
        $pid = $_GET['pid'];
        $updateQuery = "UPDATE productdb.tbl_correlationwafer SET zone_enable='0' WHERE zone='$zone' AND lotid='$pid'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$updateQuery);
         if($result){
             echo "<script>window.history.go(-1);</script>";
             //echo "<script>return false;</script>";
         }else{
             echo "<script>window.history.go(-1);</script>";
             //echo "<script>return false;</script>";
         }

flush();
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Below is from `test_1.php`.

```
 <?php 

// ini_set("memory_limit","512M");
include("_dbconn.php");
include("//sgewsnant21.amk.st.com/ewsweb/wwwroot/library/common7/db_config.inc");
include("//sgewsnant21.amk.st.com/ewsweb/wwwroot/library/common7/standard_defines.inc");
session_start();

        $zone = $_GET['id'];
        $pid = $_GET['pid'];
        $updateQuery2 = "UPDATE productdb.tbl_correlationwafer SET zone_enable='1' WHERE zone='$zone' AND lotid='$pid'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$updateQuery2);
         if($result){
             echo "<script>window.history.go(-1);</script>";
             //echo "<script>return false;</script>";
         }else{
             echo "<script>window.history.go(-1);</script>";
             //echo "<script>return false;</script>";
         }

flush();
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Instead of clicking a link you'll have to use AJAX then, to send the necessary parameters to the server, and handle the response in JavaScript.

Comment: ID attributes **must** be unique so generating multiple elements within a loop will break that rule

Comment: @CBroe I never use ajax before. Can u please show me some example?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert so, please, correct me if I'm wrong.

As far as I can see, you're passing query parameters through an `<a></a>`. As it has an URL specified in the `href` attribute, it will redirect you right there.

I would definitely use Ajax, as suggested by @CBroe. It will allow you to pass whatever parameters you need for updating your database to the server, without reloading the page. You'll be also able to improve the user experience, and refactor some of the code you've shared.

Take a look at this [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#submitting_forms_and_uploading_files), it helped me a lot to understand how it works.

Good luck!